# Eliminar el "STATE" en el emulador de Android

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

Recién estoy aprendiendo a desarrollar aplicaciones móviles a través de visual studio con Xamarin, he notado que al compilar mi proyecto, el emulador realiza un "Load State" y al detenerlo, realiza un "Saving State".

Por error oprimí el botón que retorna al desktop de Android, pero ahora cada que que requiero compilar, el emulador se muestra en el Desktop (el ultimo state guardado), entonces no puedo probar mi aplicación, ¿hay alguna manera de resetear ese state? o ¿Que estoy haciendo mal al compilar?

Comment: Hace mucho que no hago pruebas con emulador, pero si mi memoria no me falla puedes abrir el menu de aplicaciones del emulador y abrir tu app.

Comment: ¿Tu que me recomiendas mas para el desarrollo de aplicaciones móviles? por ahora solo me estoy enfocando en Android

Comment: en general depende del stack que quieras manejar, yo empece nativo pero como mi fuerte era .Net me pase a Xamarin, de ahi pase a Nativescript por que empece a trabajar con Angular y me gusto.